# Underscore suddenly a word boundary

Tags: vimrc

I now have Vim version 8.1.2102 from Sep 30 2019 15:45:59 on Fedora 30. For some reason the word boundary in C++ code now also includes the underscore somehow, so I see this:

[image]

When I have the cursor over that and press `*`, it will only search for `quark`. When I do `<C-[>` it will try to search for the tag `quark`.

There are a bunch of plugins:

```
$ ls .vim/bundle
molokai/             vim-eunuch/         vim-regex-collection/
SingleCompile/       vim-fish/           vim-repeat/
syntastic/           vim-fswitch/        vim-snipmate/
tlib_vim/            vim-gutentags/      vim-surround/
vim-addon-mw-utils/  vim-headings/       vim-unimpaired/
vim-dirvish/         Vim-Jinja2-Syntax/  VOoM/
vim-dokuwiki/        vim-mathematica/
```

I have not changed the plugins but Vim got updated and somehow this has changed. How can I further triage and fix this issue?

---

In the C++ code file I have this setting:

```
iskeyword=a-z,A-Z
```

In my whole `.vim` directory there is not a single spot where this is set to anything nonsensical:

```
$ grep -R iskeyword .
./bundle/vim-fish/ftplugin/fish.vim:setlocal iskeyword=@,48-57,-,_,.,/
./bundle/vim-mathematica/syntax/mma.vim:setlocal iskeyword+=`,$
./bundle/vim-mathematica/syntax/mma.vim:setlocal iskeyword-=:,-
```

Fish is a shell and mma is for Wolfram Language code. Since the `filetype` is set to `cpp`, neither of them should be invoked.

I could just add `set iskeyword+=_` to my `.vimrc` but that does not seem right.

Comment: What about `grep -R isk .`? (Vim commands/options can be abbreviated.)

Comment: Please update the question with verbatim output of `:verbose set iskeyword?` since that would be a great clue into troubleshooting this! Also, what does `:set ft?` say?

Answer (score 3):

This is configured by the `'iskeyword'` setting. You can check the current value and what set that value by running the command:

```
:verbose set iskeyword?
```

See [`:help 'iskeyword'`](http://www.vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27) and [`:help 'isfname'`](http://www.vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27isfname%27) for details of this setting. It is a comma delimited string which usually contains a specific `_` item.

If the thing that is setting the option incorrectly cannot be configured not to do so, you can fix this by placing settings in a file in a subdirectory of your [`.vim/after` directory](http://www.vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#after-directory): the precise best location depends on exactly what is breaking the setting in the first place, but I'm guessing adding either of the following lines to `.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim` would work for you:

```
" Just add an underscore
setlocal iskeyword+=_

" Reset to default
setlocal iskeyword&
```

Comment: It says: `iskeyword=a-z,A-Z` and *no mapping found* for `*` and *no mapping found* for `<C-]>`. So shouldn't there also be numbers in there?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: @MartinUeding The numbers just specify ASCII characters by their byte value, so they're not 100% necessary. But for your purposes there should definitely be an `_`. Does it not tell you what set the value?

Comment: For `ft` it tells where it is set, but for `iskeyword` it does not tell me any location.

Comment: @MartinUeding What happens to the value if you type `:set iskeyword&` and then check it again with `:set iskeyword?` in the C++ buffer?

Comment: If that *doesn't* fix it, somehow your installation of Vim has an odd default setting of `iskeyword`, and I think the correct solution is to set a more reasonable value in your `vimrc`. e.g `set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`. You mentioned in your question that you don't want to set it in your `vimrc`, but I'm not sure why. Setting it for the filetype as I suggest in my answer will also work. (If you set it specifically: not to the default)

Comment: After resetting it in the C++ buffer it indeed comes out as `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`. Perhaps it is a system-wide installed plugin or so. I will try to grep for it later.

Comment: @MartinUeding Looks like it: I just don't understand why it's not reported by `:verbose` (which normally works fine for system and user plugins alike). You might be able to get a head start on your grepping by viewing the output of `:scriptnames` in your C++ buffer, which will show you which Vimscript files have been loaded.

Comment: On a Vim instance without a file it told me that it was last set by `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/boxes.vim`. I have removed the Fedora package `boxes-vim` and now the `iskeyword` is back to its default.